# How get the result of a boolean method in one class into an if statement of another class in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods, boolean

I'm writing a program that gathers a first name, a last name, and the sales figure of an employee. I have all the basics working perfectly but I have an issue. In my while loop I have programmed it so if the user enters "add" then it will call a method I made in a different class and add whatever number they entered to the employees current sales total, same for subtraction. But if I need to write an if statement that checks if the subtraction is unsuccessful and if it is display an "error".

```
 public class EmployeeInfo
 {
 //class constants

 //class variables
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private int itemsSold;
 private int employeeTotal;

public EmployeeInfo(String first, String last, int sold)
{

    //local constants

    //local variables

    /********************   Start Constructor  *****************/

    //Calls the first and last name, and the amount of items sold
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    itemsSold = sold;

}//End constructor


 public void addition(int itemsSold)
   {
      //local constants

      //local variables


      /********************   Start main method  *****************/

      //Adds the items sold to the employee total
      employeeTotal = itemsSold + employeeTotal;

}//end addition


 public void subtraction(int itemsSold)
 {
       //local constants

       //local variables

       /********************   Start main method  *****************/

       //Subtracts the items not sold to the employee total
       employeeTotal = (employeeTotal - itemsSold);

}//end subtraction


public boolean booleanMethod(boolean result)
{
       //local constants

       //local variables

       /********************   Start main method  *****************/

       if(employeeTotal < 0)
       {
           result = false;
       }
       else
       {
           result = true;
       }

       return result;

 }//End booleanMethod

   public String toString()
    {
       //local constants

       //local variables


       /******************************************************/

       return String.format(Util.setLeft(45,"Eployee Name and Sales Figures") + "\n\n" + Util.setLeft(40, "First Name: ") + Util.setRight(30, firstName) +
       "\n" + Util.setLeft(40, "Last Name : ") + Util.setRight(30, lastName) + "\n" + Util.setLeft(40, "Items Sold: ") + Util.setRight(30, Integer.toString(employeeTotal)));

   }//end to string

}//end employeeInfo
```

and this is a partial part of the class that uses the booleanMethod, method

```
while(soldItems != QUIT)
    {

        //Clear screen then prompt the user to add or subtract
        System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.print(Util.setLeft(35, "Add or Subtract: "));
        input = Keyboard.readString();
        System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

        //if the user enters add the program will add to the employee total
        if(input.equals(ADD))
        {
            info.addition(soldItems);

        }

        //else the program will subtract from the employee total
        else
        {
            info.subtraction(soldItems);

            if (info.booleanMethod(false))
            {
                System.out.print("Error");
                System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
            }
        }
```

the tool completes successfully but it doesn't display the error message it just displays my line asking for another sales figure, how do I get it to actually work?

Comment: Have the subtraction method perform the validation and return the `boolean` result of the operation

Comment: Rather than allow an instance to take an invalid state, such as having a negative number of items sold, it is usually preferrable for methods to fail.  For example, your method `EmployeeInfo.subtraction()` might check whether there were enough items available to subtract.  If so, it would perform the subtraction and return `true`; otherwise, it would return `false` without doing anything else.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried that already and that didn't work either.

Comment: in the booleanMethod method, do a sysout of the total to see what value it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by placing the responsibility of the `subtraction` to perform the validation...

```
public boolean subtraction(int itemsSold)
{
    //local constants

    //local variables

    /********************   Start main method  *****************/

    //Subtracts the items not sold to the employee total
    employeeTotal = (employeeTotal - itemsSold);

    return employeeTotal < 0;
}//end subtraction
```

Then simply use the return result to determine what should be done...

```
if (!info.subtraction(soldItems)) {
    //...
}
```

IMHO, `subtraction` should actually stop before it reaches a possible invalid state, for example...

```
public boolean subtraction(int itemsSold)
{
    //local constants

    //local variables

    /********************   Start main method  *****************/

    if (employeeTotal - itemsSold >= 0) {
        //Subtracts the items not sold to the employee total
        employeeTotal = (employeeTotal - itemsSold);
        return true; 
    } 

    return false;
}//end subtraction
```

Comment: that made it so the subtraction doesn't go through but I still need to display the error message. edit: it figured it out

Comment: `if (!info.subtraction(soldItems)) { // Display error }` - the "suggested" fix will still return `false` if the operation could not be executed

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
if (!info.booleanMethod(false))
```

which means that it's false. Your current code means

```
if(true)
```

Actually there is no reason to pass in the boolean at all. The boolean belongs in the booleanMethod() method.

It should look like this:

```
public boolean booleanMethod()
{


//local constants

   //local variables

   /********************   Start main method  *****************/

   if(employeeTotal < 0)
   {
       return false;
   }
   else
   {
       return  true;
   }

}
```

and you should call it like this:

```
if (!info.booleanMethod())
```